# C++ Multidimensional arrays generating segmentation faults?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I am writing a script which must copy some names into a multidimensional array, print the contents of the array and then deallocate the memory and terminate. The problem I am having is that when I run the script it only prints out the last name entered. Here is what I have done. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void createArray(int n);
void addDetail(char*& name, char*& surname);
void printArray();
void clear();

char ***details;
int used;
int size;

int main()
{
    createArray(3);

    char* tmpName = new char[20];
    char* tmpSurName = new char[120];

    strcpy(tmpName, "nameA");
    strcpy(tmpSurName, "surnameA");
    addDetail(tmpName,tmpSurName);

    strcpy(tmpName, "nameB");
    strcpy(tmpSurName, "surnameB");
    addDetail(tmpName,tmpSurName);

    strcpy(tmpName, "nameC");
    strcpy(tmpSurName, "surnameC");
    addDetail(tmpName,tmpSurName);

    clear();
    return 0;
}

void createArray(int n)
{
    details= new char**[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        details[i] = new char*[2];
    size = n;
    used = 0;
}

void addDetail(char*& name, char*& surname)
{
    if(occupation < size)
    {
        details[used][0] = name;
        details[used][1] = surname;
        used++;
    }else{
        cout << "Array Full " << endl;
    }
}

void printArray()
{
    for(int i=0; i<used; i++)
        cout << details[i][0] << " " << details[i][1] << endl;
}

void clear()
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        delete [] details[i];
        details[i] = 0;
    }
    delete [] details;
    details=0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using **string** ?

Comment: If you're using C++ then why not use `string` and `vector` for this instead of *old skool* C-style idioms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory for `details[used][0]` and `details[used][1]` so it's using whatever random address was in those locations.

Since this is C++ you can use string instead perhaps? `std::string **details;`. This should work with your existing code, except that it will leak memory.

Better still is to use a vector of vectors.

Something like:
`std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > details;`

Then the `createArray` function can go away completely and `addDetail` becomes simpler:

```
std::vector<string> newName;
newName.push_back(name);
newName.push_back(surname);
details.push_back(newName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) I am sure that would work... however it is a requirement that we have all the functions here; and also that we use char ***details. XD. How can I make this work using what I have? I don't fully understand how to allocate memory for details[used][0] ... I thought I did this in createArray()?

Answer (score 0):

It is because each time, you are effectively storing the pointer `tmpName` and `tmpSurName` in the array `details`. Then in the next iteration, you overwrite the contents of the memory where `tmpName` and `tmpSurName` point to, so at the end you'll have a list that contains the last name/surname n times.

To solve it, you need to re-allocate tmpName and tmpSurName before *each* call to addDetail.

Btw, why do you need to use an (ewww) `char***`, and can't use e.g. the STL?

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is happening is that you are not adding the string to the array, you are adding a pointer to name and surname. Every instance is pointing at that variable, so when you ask the array what it contains it goes and asks name and surname, which will only contain the last value.

Also that array, are you sure its working how you want it to work? Arrays are... concrete things. Your essentially saying "I want 5 of these, they will be this big (based on the type you put in)" and the computer quietly goes "well I'll set aside space for those here and you can put them in when your ready". When your code puts those names in there, there really isn't any prep on where to store them. If you fill up that space and go beyond you go to bad places. So what you should do is have that last * of char*** be a pointer to a char[120] so that you know (for your purposes atleast) it never gets filled up. Do that in your createArray function after you have created the outer arrays.

Comment: Oh I see! Ok thats cool but now how do I fix? If I dereference name/surname then it gives me errors?

Comment: @Tim I haven't done C++ in a bit so my pointer skills are a little rusty. But in the line "void addDetail(char*& name, char*& surname)" those ampersands are creating reference variables. You could try removing those and that might do it but I'm not 100% on that since the array is still involved (and an array is a pointer). Its been a long time since I needed to manage char*s. Also it helps us (in the future) if you post errors you get so we know exactly whats occuring. I do suggest researching Reference Variables as they are important and you should be aware what that line I referenced means

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting your temporary buffers rather than making new buffers for each entry in the array. As a result, only the last data written to the buffer survives.

Here's a rough guide on one way to fix it, though this sample may have some problems - I made no attempt to compile or test this.

This portion of main belongs in addDetail:

```
char* tmpName = new char[20];
char* tmpSurName = new char[120];

strcpy(tmpName, "nameA");
strcpy(tmpSurName, "surnameA");
```

So, your new addDetail would look something like:

```
void addDetail(char*& name, char*& surname)
{
    if(occupation < size)
    {
        details[used][0] = new char[20];
        details[used][1] = new char[120];
        strcpy(details[used][0], name);
        strcpy(details[used][1], surname);
        used++;
    }else{
        cout << "Array Full " << endl;
    }
}
```

And it would be called from main like:

```
addDetail("nameA", "surnameA");
```

You'd need to update clear to properly cleanup the allocations made in addDetail though.